# Rails: How to add an object through a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to rails and I have this web application that allows users to create new print Jobs Using Rails 4

app/models/job.erb

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :job_type
end
```

app/models/job_type.erb

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end
```

In the new job creation form user must choose a job type for his new job from a list, Which I managed to get it throw the following code.

app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>

      .....

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :job_type_id %><br>
        <%= f.collection_select :job_type_id, JobType.all,:id,:name %>
      </div>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

And through some coffee script I managed to add "Other" Option to the Job Types menu, Which fires the modal #myModal to add a new JobType to the database if its not exist...

app/assets/javascript/jobs.coffee

```
$('#job_job_type_id').append("<option>Other</option>")
$('#job_job_type_id').change ->
  jobType = $('#job_job_type_id :selected').text()
  if jobType == "Other"
    $('#myModal').modal('show')
  else
    $('#myModal').modal('hide')
```

The Code is working good and fires the bootstrap modal. But that's it I don't know what to do next?

I've tried a lot of code and reviewed a lot of questions, but I didn't get to make this modal able to add a new JobType and update the list, I've figured that needs some modification to controllers and fancy AJAX code beyond my knowledge...

I have some questions here

1) What should I put in the modal code to be able to add a new JobType to the database, Then return to the new Job creation form and the newly created JobType selected

2) Which controllers need to be modified? and How? What AJAX Code  need?

3) How to re-factor the Job _form ? Can I put the modal code in a new Partial? If yes how to implement this ?

I hope you can help me, I've been struggling to solve this issue for days.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first, to answer your questions:

*1) What should I put in the modal code to be able to add a new JobType to the database, Then return to the new Job creation form and the newly created JobType selected*

Your modal will add a form, essentially the form you probably have under `app/views/job_types/_form.html.erb`, but it will have a button that will submit via AJAX instead of form submit.

2) Which controllers need to be modified? and How? What AJAX Code need?

You will need to add a method to the `job_types_controller` that can handle the aforementioned AJAX call.  It will need to:

- Save the new job type
- Return a success status and the newly created entity to the caller.

*3) How to re-factor the Job _form ? Can I put the modal code in a new Partial? If yes how to implement this ?*

You need to have a method that, when called, adds a new option to the listbox.  You can put the modal code in a partial, or not, up to you; that decision has no consequence in regard to the functionality of all this.

So, what do you need to do here:

**SERVER (CONTROLLER):**

1) Create a method in `config/routes.rb` that can handle an AJAX call.

```
resources :job_types do
  post :append, on: :collection
end
```

This adds a custom resource route.  Because we add it this way, we automatically get the URLHelper function `append_job_types_path`.

2) Implement this method in `controllers/job_types_controller.rb` to save a new JobType and return it (and, most importantly, it's ID) to the caller.

```
def append
  job_type = JobType.new
  job_type.name = params[:job_type_name]
  if job_type.save
    render :status => 201, :json => { id: job_type.id, name: job_type.name }
  else
    err_msg = job_type.errors.empty?? 'Save failed' : job_type.errors.full_messages.join('; ')
    render :status => 400, :json => { message: err_msg }
  end
end
```

If save goes well, the ID and name of the new entity will be returned as JSON to the caller.  If not, we return an error and any validation messages.

Now, we are ready to utilize these methods...

**CLIENT (VIEW):**

1) Create a button that can launch the modal

You've already done this!

2) Add a form to the modal that can submit a job type

```
<%= form_tag(append_job_types_path) do %>
  Enter Job Name:<br/>
  <input type="text" name="new_job_type_name" id="new_job_type_name" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" id="append_job_type_submit" />
<% end %>
```

And really, it doesn't need to be in a form since we're submitting via AJAX, but you'll probably get some styling help by using one. However, the `id` attributes here are important for the next steps.  Note that I'm using `form_tag` here instead of `form_for`.  That's because I won't be attaching anything to the form (or submitting it for that matter).

3) On submit (er, on button click), send the name entered by the user to new AJAX method

Here, we'll use unobtrusive javascript to hook a listener method to the submit button.  You can put this code at the bottom of the view, or you can move it to coffeescript:

```
javascript:
  $("#append_job_type_submit").click(function() {
    var name = $("#new_job_type_name").val();
    //TODO: validation on the name, ensure it's not blank, etc
    $.ajax({
      url: '/job_types/append',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {job_type_name: name},
      success: function(data) {
        //TODO: Handle success
      },
      error: function(err) {
        //TODO: Handle error
      }
    });
  });
```

Here, we are sending an AJAX call to the server method, passing the name the user entered.  Note that I left space for simple validation you can do prior to submission

4) Upon response, append the new option to the listbox.

This continues the function from above:

```
javascript:
  $("#append_job_type_submit").click(function() {
    var name = $("#new_job_type_name").val();
    //TODO: validation on the name, ensure it's not blank, etc
    $.ajax({
      url: '/job_types/append',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {job_type_name: name},
      success: function(data) {
        var sel = $("#job_type_id");
        sel.append('<option value="' + data.id + '">' + data.name + '</option>');
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        alert("New job type " + data.name + " created.");
        //TODO: probably be nice to auto-select this option; I'll leave that exercise to the alert reader
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert(err.responseJSON.message);
      }
    });
  });
```

Now, the user can pick the option from the select box, and the new option has been saved to the database (regardless of whether or not they create the new job).

**Disclaimer**: I have not tested this code, or even checked to see if it compiles.  But it should work, and regardless, this is the pattern you want to follow, so if nothing else, at least you have the direction now.

Now, all that said, I would still recommend the other approach without AJAX that I suggested, as it cuts out most of these steps, but that's just me. Feel free to accept whichever answer helps YOU get YOUR task done the way YOU want to do it.

Note: I decided to post this in addition to aldrien's answer as mine has a few differences that I found significant enough to warrant it:

- A success and failure response should return success/failure status code. Having it always return success is a bit misleading. I think status codes are an important part of any REST design, even something as small as this.
- I'd only recommend using `match` routes as a last resort.  Resourceful routes are cleaner and clearer, and they give you more out the box as well.  Also, I like the route under `/job_types` and not just floating at the root.
- Also more of a standards thing, should be a POST request instead of a GET; we are creating a new entity after all.
- Bug: The append method should yield `data.id` for the option value, not `data.title` (which should be `data.name` according to the original code). Otherwise, the value will not be the ID, and attempted save will fail.

Comment: !, Thank you a lot, Your answer was clear, You walked me throw the answer step by step explaining every thing. And It worked perfectly as I wanted it to be. except one thing: `<%= form_tag(append_job_type_path) do %>` 
It kept give me an error `undefined local variable or method 'append_job_type_path'`, But when I changed it to: `<%= form_tag(append_job_type_path) do %>` It worked just fine, Which "And I'm embarrassed to say" a solution I'm not fully understand. But any way Thank You

Comment: Thanks, I updated that in the answer for posterity. If you want any clarification on anything, feel free to comment and ask!

Answer (score 1):

If I may offer an alternative...

Your approach is going to require some advanced coding methods and, if you are uncomfortable with AJAX, this may be a difficult road.

As an alternative, I would suggest that instead of showing a modal, just show/hide a textbox within the existing form to house the Other name:

```
<input type="text" name="other_job_type" />
```

Then, when you submit the form, as you know it will go to JobController#create (or #update for existing jobs).  In there, you can get this field:

```
def create
  save_successful = false
  @job = Job.new params[:job]
  other_job_type = params[:other_job_type]
  if other_job_type
    new_job_type = JobType.new
    new_job_type.name = other_job_type
    save_successful = new_job_type.save
    @job.job_type = new_job_type
  end
  if save_successful && @job.save
    # redirect to success page
  else
    # render new/edit with error messages
  end
end
```

By doing it this way, you only create a new job type if the user actually submits the job form, which is nice.

Use the `save_successful` pattern if you want to enforce validations on the JobType, such as a unique name.  Then the save will fail if the user attempts to save with an existing job type.  You could also just select the existing one for them, but I'll leave that to you if you choose to do that.

Again, all this follows the same pattern you are using now, just a new text field and a little more processing in the controller.

If you want, I can detail the answer to your question in terms of using AJAX methods to get this to work, as the steps, though much lengthier are pretty deterministic, but it's probably overkill for your use case.  That said, I hate not actually answering the given question, regardless of my personal opinion of the approach, so just let me know.

Comment: I Really hope you can answer it using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, set up the button or form in your modal for triggering submit function.

**Secondly**, set up/check Routes/URL to be used for AJAX method.

As well as setting Controller function for saving new job type.

example in **controller**:

```
def create
  job_type = JobType.new
  job_type.title = params[:job_type]
  if job_type.save
   render :json => job_type
  else
   render :json => "some error here."
  end
end
```

**Finally**, make AJAX function for sending data.

```
$("#add_new_job_type").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/add_new_job_type',
        type: 'GET', // or POST
        data: {job_type: $("#field_contains_new_value").val()}
    }).done(function(data){
        // Do some validation for checking error response (like if statement)
        // Append the new data (job type to select option tag)
        new_job_type = "<option value="'+data.title+'">" + data.title + "</option>"
        $('#job_job_type_id').append(new_job_type);
        ....
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
    });

});
```

Notes: ***add_new_job_type*** used in *AJAX url* is the custom routes.

In **config/routes.rb** (custom routes):

```
match 'add_new_job_type' => 'job_types#add_new_job_type', :via => :post #or :get
```

In your **JobTypes Controller**, you must have:

```
def add_new_job_type
  job_type = JobType.new
  job_type.title = params[:job_type]
  if job_type.save
   render :json => job_type
  else
   render :json => "some error here."
  end
end
```

Modify the code as you wish.

Comment: What do you mean by: set up/check Routes/URL to be used for AJAX method.?? Can you explain your answer more?

Comment: Hi @MoatazZaitoun, if you have resources :job_types in config/routes.rb, the default path for create method is "/job_types/new". I will make custom routes for you. Please check updated code.